# When the app is in pinned mode and I logout, the signin activity is shown. But, if I click back button, it goes to previous activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I pin the app in the mobile, now if I logout from the app, it goes to the SignIn page but if I click on back button, it must show the native alert i.e. "to unpin the app......". But what happens is it goes to the previous page.

on logout pressed:

```
val intent = Intent(activity, SplashActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_KEYS.IS_SIGNED_OUT, true)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        activity?.startActivity(intent) 
   activity?.finishAffinity()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Logout pressed you are sending the user to Splash screen which i guess open sign in activity so splash screen still there even after `activity?.finishAffinity()`

The scenario like this

> Button Pressed
>
> Finish Affinity
>
> Splash Created
>
> Sign In Created

so sign in not the only created activity.

I suggest to send user to sign in page directly or in splash screen finish the activity after the intent to sign in one

Comment: splash activity is the signin activiy.....both are same